# Open Layers with NPM and Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, openlayers-3

I'm trying to import Open Layers 3 into my application using NPM and Webpack for bundling, but I am receiving the error and the map not rendering:

> ./~/openlayers/dist/ol.js Critical dependencies: 567:411-418 This
>   seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's
>   not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better
>   results.  @ ./~/openlayers/dist/ol.js 567:411-418

Importing Open Layers using:

```
import ol from 'openlayers';
```

I've tried to use the `noParse` option in in Webpack: `noParse: /dist\/ol.js/` with no luck.

How to use Open Layers with NPM and Webpack?

Comment: I had to Import the entire module's contents using `import * as ol from 'openlayers';` and it rendered the map. But still with that annoying warning message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apperently I had to locate it exactly where it was:

Working solution:

```
var Path = require("path");
noParse: [Path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/openlayers/dist/ol.js")]
```